# VBA comparing cells

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a little code to mark the differences in two different tables.

When I run the code, there are many right "hits", but for some reason, sometimes the exact same value is marked as different. This mostly happened with numbers or if the alignment is not the same.

To get rid of the alignment- and formatting- problem I wrote/found the following Code:

```
Sub makeBeautiful()

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("bank-accountsNew")
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("bank-accountsOld")
    
    n = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    m = sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
    For j = 1 To m
    For i = 1 To n
    If sht.Cells(i, j).Value = "null" Then
    sht.Cells(i, j).Value = " "
    End If
    Next i
    Next j
    
    For Each wks In Worksheets
        wks.Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        wks.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Next wks
    
    sht.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
    sht2.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"

End Sub
```

As far as I can tell, this works just fine.

To mark the differences, I have the following Code:

```
Sub changeFinder()

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim o As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim Result As String
    Dim item1 As String
    Dim item2 As String

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("bank-accountsNew")
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("bank-accountsOld")

    n = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    m = sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    k = sht2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    l = sht2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    For j = 1 To m
    sht.Columns(j + 1).Insert
    sht.Columns(j + 1).Insert
    For i = 2 To n
    sht.Cells(i, j + 1).Value = Application.VLookup(sht.Cells(i, 1), sht2.Columns(1).Resize(, j), j, False)

    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To n
    item1 = sht.Cells(i, j).Text
    item2 = sht.Cells(i, j + 1).Text
    Result = StrComp(item1, item2)
    sht.Cells(i, j + 2) = Result
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To n
        If sht.Cells(i, j + 2) = 1 Then
        sht.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next i
    sht.Columns(j + 1).Delete
    sht.Columns(j + 1).Delete
    
    Next j


End Sub
```

My idea was to create two new column next to every column I want to compare. Fill these two new column with the fitting value and a number to check either these values are the same or not. If not, the original value should be marked in red.

I have in both table almost the same bank accounts numbers as column 3.
Some of them are marked as different and some them are not marked as different, but in only case they are not the same. So, my code does not work properly.

As far as I can tell, every value is equally aligned and equally formatted, so I don´t know what could cause Excel to think that the same numbers are different. :/

Table B is created by a json.file. Table A ist created by PowerQuery with two tables, which I have from a json.file.

I hope someone can help me here a litle bit.

Sincerely,
Julian

Comment: `Cell.Text` will return what is *displayed* in a cell. If you want to compare values, use `Cell.Value`

Comment: I replaced Cell.Text with Cell.Value, but then I got an error message telling me there is a type dismatch. The line "item2 = sht.Cells(i, j + 1).Value" was highlighted by VBA.

Comment: Can you give an example of 2 values that are marked as different when they shouldn't be, investigating those will probably explain what the problem is. Check for leading/trailing spaces. If the alignment is different it suggests numbers being treated as text. Are values all numeric or alpha-numeric or mixture of both ?

Comment: I'm thinking if it happens with numbers and alignment - one table could be storing the numbers as numbers, while the other stores it as text.  They'd have different alignments then.  It could also be how many decimal places it's showing - one could be 1.001, while the other is 1.00 but both are set to only show two decimal places so look the same.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than repeated VLookups consider using a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub changeFinder()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, r2 As Long
    Dim lastcol As Long, c As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sht1 = .Sheets("bank-accountsNew")
        Set sht2 = .Sheets("bank-accountsOld")
    End With
    
    ' build look up to sheet2
    Dim dict As Object, id As String, n As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With sht2
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' scan down sheet
        For r = 2 To lastrow
           id = Trim(.Cells(r, 1))
           If dict.exists(id) Then
               MsgBox "Error - duplicate id " & id, vbCritical, sht2.Name & " row " & r
               Exit Sub
           ElseIf Len(id) > 0 Then
               dict.Add id, r
           End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' compare with sheet 1
    With sht1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With .UsedRange
            lastcol = .Columns.Count
            .Interior.Color = xlNone 'clear sheet
        End With
        
        ' scan down sheet
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            id = Trim(.Cells(r, 1))
            ' check exists on sheet2
            If Not dict.exists(id) Then
                .Rows(r).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 255, 128)
                n = n + 1
            Else
                r2 = dict(id) ' sheet 2 row
                
                ' scan across columns
                For c = 2 To lastcol
                   If Trim(.Cells(r, c)) <> Trim(sht2.Cells(r2, c)) Then
                      .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 128, 0)
                      n = n + 1
                      'Debug.Print .Cells(r, c), sht2.Cells(r2, c)
                   End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' result
    If n > 0 Then
        MsgBox n & " differences found", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "No differences found", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```